# Hosting web app on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

*I hav made a small demo web app(using html5, and jquery mobile) 
*I have installed and set up Xampp
*set passwords for local server
* I am confused as in what to do next, where do i store my .html files and other resources
*I need to test my app on a network
*I want to set up a database using xampp ,(i have no idea how to)
*edit: since its a mobile web app, i want to test it from my mobile, is it possible by hosting it on my pc ? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the apache server running on xampp, you have to put the files in the /htdocs map. This is usually located in something like C:/xampp/htdocs. Then you go to your localhost in your browsers, so localhost and then /example.html.
This would be for example localhost/example.html, this would redirect to the example.html file in the htdocs folder.
Then if you want to set up an mySQL database you should take a look around at localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: Are you sure you have eg.html in C:/xampp/htdocs and the apache server running?

Comment: Yes server is running too,  the address i tried was localhost/eg.html

Comment: Are you using a windows or a mac? For most windows devices 127.0.0.1/eg.html will work as well. EDIT: most likely windows i think, as you're using XAMPP

Comment: See my question, aftr edit.. How can i view my app from another device (mobile)

Comment: Then you will need a home server, this is not possible with xampp. You could use a raspberry pi for this, if it is for your own usage only.

Comment: Yes it worked, but my question is using it in a non local device,

Comment: Yes, xampp only works with your own computer. You need to get a server if you want to host your website outside your own computer. You could also hire some space at a web hosting provider.

Comment: Isnt ras pi a hardware dev board? And does server.com provide free server space, ever used it? I just googled for " free server" ended up with freeserver.com

Comment: Ras pi can be used to make a really cheap, low-spec server. But as you are getting started I would go with a web hosting provider. You won't get it for free. About 5€ a month would be reasonable for a good contract.

Comment: I have an old spare computer( 32 bit, 4yrs old)..  How can i turn it into a server, i need a quick solution( walkthrough). I can install ubuntu on it if needed

Comment: Take a look here, this should be a detailed enough walkthrough: http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/6398-howto-create-your-own-linux-home-server-using-debian/